# .htaccess url rewriting

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have made a blog which I have hosted on 000webhost.com. I want to use `.htaccess` to rewrite my `urls`, for example:

Home----index.php-----index

etc.

Also, I want to hide the URLs in which query strings are present.

So far I have written this code in my `.htaccess` file but I don't know why the code is not working.

```
RewriteBase     /
Options         +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteRule     ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC]
```

Comment: are you sure the rewrite module is allowed and activated ?

Comment: In addition to the above question, are you allowing override from all?

Comment: hey i am new to htaccess ...... i hav read the documentation of the website...........rewrite mod is activated//// and what is override from all......?????

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should move away from 000webhost **as soon as you can**; you get what you pay for, and they wipe accounts without notice.